# How to get user input from UItextfield and add it to an array?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I am working in swift. I have a textfield that is in a tableview cell. I am trying to store the text of each text field in the tableview so they when the user adds or deletes a row, and then the tableview reloads data, that the text fields stay filled in with the appropriate data.

I tried adding a textfielddidendeditting function but for some reason it is not being called.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

tableViewController:

```
import UIKit

var rowCount = 0
var textArray = [String]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rowCount
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    return cell
}

@IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any) {
    rowCount = rowCount + 1
    textArray.append("")
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        rowCount = rowCount - 1
        textArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
    }
}


}
```

tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textField.delegate = self

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let myIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let newText = textField.text
        textArray.insert(newText, at: myIndexPath)
    }

    return true
}

}
```

Comment: "I tried adding a textfielddidendeditting function but for some reason it is not being called" But unless you show us your code, we cannot tell you what that reason is.

Comment: Also, this is a very common need (communicate text from textfield in table view cell into table view's model data). Did you try searching before asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I could suggest (without any code insight given) you could do the following:

1. Use a callback in your cell, which gets called every time the textfield ends editing:

.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
       var textHasChanged: ((String) -> Void)?
       ...
    } 
    extension MyTableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // this gets called every time the user ends editing the text field
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            let newValue = textField.text //here you have your value

            // now save it to your data source
            self.textHasChanged(newValue)
        }
    }
```

2. In a initializer or in `awakeFromNib()` function (depends on your usage), set the `.delegate` property of the textfield to `self`
3. Now, to have each cell display the value from the datasource and to apply the changed text to your tableView datasource, add the following lines to your UITableViewController:

.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var textArray: [String] = ["abc", "def"]
    ...
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textField.text = textArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textHasChanged = { (newValue) in
            self.textArray[indexPath.row] = newValue
        }
        return cell
}
```

Just comment if you have further questions

Comment: Hey Muli. Thanks for the advice. My first mistake was I forgot to set the .delegate to self. Now that I have fixed that simple mistake I would like to set the new textfield text to a specific index in an array which is the same as the row that the textfield is in. The problem here is I do not know how to get the indexPath.row of the current row when inside the tableViewCell. Therefore I am getting and error when I define myIndexPath. Any tips?

Comment: see updated answer. The mistake you're making is trying to access the tableView and its datasource from your cell. You have to use another delegate or a callback like I did. Add the callback from step 1 to you UITableViewCellFeel, call the function in your textFieldShouldEdit and apply step 3 to your TableViewController. Feel free for further questions.

Comment: @Ilya what the status concerning your question? Did you solve it? Do you need further help?